# Derivation of Laplace transform of Bessel function, where does initial condition go?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the Laplace transform of $J_0(t)$ given in Spiegel's "Laplace Transforms" book, on p. 23 of my copy. One way is to use the power series representation for $J_0(t)$. The other way is to take the Laplace transform of Bessel's differential equation $tJ_0''(t) + J_0'(t) + t J_0(t) = 0$, using the initial conditions $J_0(0) = 1$, $J_0'(0)=0$, however there's something that's seriously confusing me. When we do the second method, using the properties of the LT, we arrive at

$$
-\frac{d}{ds} (s^2 y -s -0) +(sy -1) - \frac{dy}{ds} = 0.
$$

Then, doing algebra and solving the separable ODE, we get $y(s) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}$, and then use the initial-value theorem to get $c=1$. The thing I don't understand is that the initial condition $Y'(0) = 0$ is not registered by this method, since it disappears when we take the derivative above, also we don't use it in the initial-value theorem, we use instead $Y(0) = 1$. But I thought two initial conditions were required to uniquely determine a 2nd order ODE like this? Also, doesn't the power series solution use $Y'(0) = 0$, and then they agree? I have a feeling that this has something to do with the fact that there are two solutions to this ODE, the solutions of the first and second kind, but I don't really understand well what is happening. Is anyone able to enlighten me?

Greg

Comment: Isn't your $-0$ in the first term doing that? I'm thinking $s^2 y(s) - s J_0(0) - J_0'(0)$ ...

Comment: Yes, but that part is lost when we differentiate.

Comment: The $J_0'(0) = 0$ condition seems implicit in your setup. Assuming the solution of interest doesn't behave too badly, for example $J_0(t)$ and $J_0''(t)$ are bounded on $0 < t < \infty$, you know that $tJ_0''(t) \to 0$ and $tJ_0(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0^+$, so $J_0'(t) \to 0$. Otherwise you'd be picking up the $Y_0$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, so the $J_0'(0)=0$ condition is superfluous, since it's implied by the ODE, under assumption that everything is bounded.  So I guess really just 1 initial condition, not 2, and that's why it doesn't uniquely determine the answer, there's another solution. Sorry that I don't seem to be able to give you the bounty.

Comment: All good, simply helping out.

Answer (score 3):

As

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\dot J_0(t)\right)+tJ_0(t)=0
$$

taking the LT with $\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\int_{t_0}^{\infty}e^{-s t}f(t) dt$ we have

$$
s\mathcal{L}[t\dot J_0(t)]+\mathcal{L}[tJ_0(t)]=t_0 \dot J_0(t_0)
$$

Choosing $t_0 = 0$ the condition on $\dot J_0(0)$ is lost.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't understand your answer. Is $t_0$ the same as $t$? Also I am not familiar with that first equation. Isn't $\dot J = J'$?

Comment: Normally $\frac{d}{dt}y(t)$ is represented as $\dot y(t)$. Here $t_0$ represents the inferior limit for the Laplace Transform. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform